# Tutorial request on implementing HiGHS solver

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, solver

In the past I have used the academic versions of Gurobi and Mosek for solving various optimization problems using various Python and Julia libraries that call the solvers.

However, I want to learn how to use freely available good solvers like [HiGHS](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/hall/HiGHS/). From the documentation I cannot figure out how exactly one interfaces the solver to Python/Julia and the examples are not quite helpful.

Is there some tutorial on how to write/implement some simple LP problem using HiGHS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python side, there are two alternatives beside scipy implementation.

You can use PuLP dev version as explained in question [How to call HiGHS solver from python PuLP MIP?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9030/how-to-call-highs-solver-from-python-pulp-mip/9033#9033)

There is also a Python package called highspy on pip but it is currently in pre-release mode so it does not show on google search (unfortunately no conveniently reachable documentation yet). [Pip link here](https://pypi.org/project/highspy/)

On R side, [there is a highs package.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highs/index.html)

Answer (score 6):

To write and solve a problem in Julia, implement it using JuMP. I assume you already installed the JuMP and HiGHS package as both install like normal Julia packages.

```
using JuMP
using HiGHS
model = Model(HiGHS.Optimizer)
```

Now define your variables, constraints and the objective on that model. Then a simple `optimize!` call should do the rest.

```
JuMP.optimize!(model)
```

You might also want to change HiGHS solver options; for that, see the README in [HiGHS.jl](https://github.com/jump-dev/HiGHS.jl) package.

Comment: Thanks, no this I know how to do this (although not sure yet how to choose which algoithm to implement e.g. simplex or IPMs etc). However, I am trying to understand what is the process that the documentation of HiGHS refers to: https://ergo-code.github.io/HiGHS/man/guide.html#Loading-a-model that is what are these (.lp, .mps) files?

Comment: That part of the HiGHS documentation is still under construction and isn't helpful. You don't need to explicitly load the model; JuMP does all of that for you. Take a look at any of the examples in the JuMP documentation that use HiGHS: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/linear/diet/. You probably also don't need to change the algorithm; just use the default.